# How do I rebuild the Quick Search Index in Sitecore 8.2?

Tags: sitecore-client, indexing, upgrade

I've upgraded my solution from sitecore 8.1 Update 1 to Sitecore 8.2 initial release. After finishing the upgrade, and configuration changes, I opened the launchpad to rebuild Quick Search Index, I couldn't find this option in the launchpad under the database section.

Any idea what might be the issue?

This step is mentioned in Post-Upgrade steps in section `1.3.4` of [Sitecore 8.2 Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/80F3ABB82AB44D6AA5722F6B654CF2A8.ashx).

[image: Quick Search Index]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system index from `<search>` node was marked `Obsolete` in config (SC8.1.3) and completely removed in Sitecore 8.2 Initial Release.

```
<search>
  <!-- Obsolete: the API that uses this section is obsolete. Please, use Sitecore.ContentSearch to configure your indexes. -->
  <configuration type="Sitecore.Search.SearchConfiguration, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="system" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
      ...
```

This index relates to the "Quick Search Index" and it has therefore also been removed from `Control Panel > Database > Rebuild search indexes` and from  **Sitecore.config**.

See this [previous question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/698/what-is-the-difference-between-an-index-and-a-search-index) if you want to find details on the difference between the indexes.

**EDIT**

Following the clarification in the question from @HarshBaid, the documentation for the upgrade guide is incorrect and as @Gatogordo's comment points out it is registered as a bug. You should still rebuild the indexes for the **Master** and **Core** databases from `Control Panel > Indexing > Indexing Manager`.

Comment: So is it correct for this option to be removed and no longer be there in sitecore 8.2?

Comment: Yes, it is correct and to be expected.

Comment: It seems there is some misunderstand about `Quick Search Index` here. I have updated the OP's question with section info and screenshot. [my edit is in queue at the moment]

Comment: The "quick search index" was removed as @jammykam says here. It is registered as a "bug" in the documentation that the rebuild step is still in the upgrade guide.

Comment: @HarshBaid No misunderstanding from my side. Like I said in my answer, `Control Panel > Database > Rebuild search indexes`

Comment: okay @Gatogordo's comment answers my doubt .. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Search indexes** are the old kind of indexes that became obsoleted recently. Sitecore functionality is now using **Content Search indexes** instead. Hence, you don't see the "Rebuild search indexes" option in the Control Panel anymore. Indexing -> Indexing Manager is the application that should be used to rebuild all indexes.

The Quick search index was the old **Search index** used by the search box at the bottom of Sitecore Desktop (a.k.a. "Quick Search"). In Sitecore 8.2, this feature uses the following **Content Search indexes** instead:

- `sitecore_core_index`
- `sitecore_master_index`
- `sitecore_web_index`

You can rebuild these indexes using the Indexing Manager found in the Control Panel.

As a conclusion, the Sitecore 8.2 Upgrade Guide is incorrect, as it includes an old step that you don't need to perform anymore.

Comment: It seems there is some misunderstand about `Quick Search Index` here. I have updated the OP's question with section info and screenshot. [my edit is in queue at the moment]

Comment: @HarshBaid Why do you think I misunderstood the question? Doesn't my answer provide the solution to the problem? :)

Comment: I think its misunderstanding here because I saw the Upgrade Guide PDF of 8.2 version and there it has been mentioned to rebuild `Quick Search Index` so your answer is not saying anything about `Quick Search Index` part which OP has asked.

Comment: @HarshBaid Yes, because in Sitecore 8.2 the Quick Search feature uses the indexes I listed.

Comment: @HarshBaid I've updated my answer. Hopefully, it makes it clearer now.

Comment: Yes it is clear now. :)